# java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having problems with java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject and I don't know how to fix this issue im trying to do a datapack for Minecraft but i have been having this issue.

videos on YouTube, here, and a couple of other places